# Create a table (DataGrid) in Windows 8 metro apps (C#/XAML)

Tags: xaml, listview, gridview, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm trying to create a table like this:
[image]

How can I do something like that using ListView or GridView? I couldnt find the right way to add the headers of the table..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I implemented a DataGrid control (with sorting, details view and navigate event) in my free library:

https://github.com/MyToolkit/MyToolkit/wiki/DataGrid

**WinRT (Windows 8.1):**

[image]

**Universal Windows App (Windows 10):**

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Not to sound overbearing, but I'd urge you take a step back from the specifics of the implementation and get a better understanding of the Windows 8 UI design principles (formerly known as Metro).

Familiarize yourself with the ["8 Traits of Great Metro Style Apps"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464920.aspx) (< 9 minute video), play with the apps out on the store now, and invest the additional time to view the full [Build presentation by Jensen Harris](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/BPS-1004).  You don't want to 'lift and shift' paradigms you've used before, but rather embrace the unique features of the platform, like its touch first nature, to rethink the navigation and build a new type of application.

From a hands-on perspective, the [XAML ListView and GridView customizing interactivity sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ListView-Interaction-ac044c3c) is a good place to start experimenting with how you can evolve from what you have posted above to a Window 8 design.

Lastly, if you are looking for something closer to what you have above - keeping in mind that it may not pass certification if it doesn't subscribe closely enough to the design principles - you may find some help [in this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/e318865a-bb7d-4295-b809-aa83e0085a1f).

Comment: Thanks Jim. It's not my first metro app, and I know about the certification process and how tough it is. But think about it... what's the best way to show a table? of course the screenshot above is just an example, it wouldnt look like this...

Comment: well, that's what the last link would hopefully lead to, but looks like it's going to be a bit of work to style it the way you want.  If it's just the headers, that's probably ok, but interacting with the drop downs and checkboxes in a metro app, will, as you know, just seem 'off'.  Alternative, is to see what 3rd parties like Telerik might have available to save some time.

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain how the table will fail the certification process? and whats the alternative?

Comment: "may not pass certification" != "will fail" :) It's not all as explicit as if you have a table it will fail. Admittedly the certification guidelines (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj128432.aspx) aren't specific to that level, but what you're looking at kind of falls under "Metro style apps behave predictably". Depending on where you are in your dev cycle on this app, consider signing up at Generation App (http://aka.ms/8in30) which gives you a free consultation with a designer for feedback and perhaps alternatives.

Comment: Admittedly I am just now designing my first Store App... and I've actually watched a couple of the videos you've listed above which are good concepts to keep in mind... But I develop business applications, lined item data is my norm. In researching this issue I've seen many people recommend rethinking the UI... which I am all for. BUT no one has yet given any design alternatives that will accomplish displaying data??

Answer (score 2):

I am also trying to have a table (DataGrid) like that but I could not. Just as a hit and trial, I have achieved it using a ListView and I have hardcoded the Items but will have to figure out to do it dynamically. I tried to include the XAML code here but it was not allowed. So here is the [link](http://sharepointrealm.blogspot.com/2013/05/a-simple-table-in-windows-store-app.html) to my post.

Here is the XAML code from the link above:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="300" Margin="0,20,0,0 ">
            <ListViewItem>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Width="150">Apple</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>100</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Width="150">Banana</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>2000</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Width="150">Oranges</TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock>1500</TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </ListViewItem>           
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Realizing this is an old answer -- how were you not allowed to include XAML? You should be able to paste, select, and tab in four spaces to have it enter code format. It might not highlight correctly, but it should be "allowed".

Answer (score 2):

Telerik provides a data grid for windows 8 store apps. Works really great. I can't tell if it also passes the certification - we'll see because i'm going to upload my app now...

here's the link:
http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-8/controls/grid.aspx

Comment: INFO: the grid app passed the store certification. Check out my app: iLOGrabber)