# How to display a data grid in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

Which is the simplest way to display a data grid in Windows 8?

For example:

```
NAME  SURNAME BIRTHDATE
John  Nime    17NOV04
Mary  Kalas   28NOV06
Dinio Fransen 17NOV04
```

The data grid does not need to be editable, just display the data.

Thank you

Comment: please correct last part of last statement. There is confusion about what you want.

Comment: I have edited. Basically I meant that the data grid is for displaying purposes, not editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This guy has done similar thing [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikezh/archive/2012/07/26/windows-8-metro-app-how-to-get-a-data-grid-like-ui-for-a-collection-of-items.aspx).

But before doing anything review answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228119/create-a-table-datagrid-in-windows-8-metro-apps-c-xaml) on SO.

Answer (score 0):

There is no data grid in windows 8 apps, but there is Grid View or List View control.