# Show row as column using GridView Xaml C# WinRT (Win 8.1)

Tags: c#, gridview, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I have a list object. Properties in "Score" class are int(PlayerId, ScoreId, TrialId)

```
List<Score> scList;

PlayerId ScoreId TrialId
Player1    25     1
Player2    28     1
Player1    34     2
Player2    21     2
```

Gridview desired Output:

```
TrialId     Player1   Player2
1            25         28
2            34         21
```

I tried datatable (add dynamic columns), but it doesn't show up in any namespace.
Is there any other way without using datatable?Do i need modified list of scList in order to achieve the desired output.

```
<GridView x:Name="GrdScore" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <GridView.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{ Binding PlayerId}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.HeaderTemplate>
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ScoreId}"></TextBlock>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
 </GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `GridView` in WinRT/XAML is not the same as a `GridView` in WPF. Its layout is actually more akin to the Windows 8 start screen.

There is no grid/table control built into WinRT/XAML and so a better choice for you might be a `ListView` control with statically specified column widths.

You might also look around to see if there are some commercial or open source implementation of a `DataGrid` for Windows 8.

Check this related answer as well:

[Create a table (DataGrid) in Windows 8 metro apps (C#/XAML)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228119/create-a-table-datagrid-in-windows-8-metro-apps-c-xaml)

Comment: thanks for the info. Can we bind multiple itemsources to the same grid? If so then it might be possible with the gridview itself..

Comment: could you please show how it can be done? like an algorithm and the namespaces that i should use...

Comment: Well, first you'd need to define what your item sources look like and how you'd want to combine them...