# ListBox Windows 10 Universal Header

Tags: xaml, listbox, winrt-xaml, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I successfully added a listbox with databinding in my xaml:

But i forgot which attribute to use for the items header.  My items contain to Textboxes "name", "money earned" and if i add items my items say for example "Mustermann", "300" but i need a headertemplate above the items which says "name" and "money earned" how do i add such a header for the items?

The xaml I already wrote isn't relevant for this question but if you are interested:

```
 <ListBox x:Name="WorkersList"  ItemsSource="{Binding}"  MaxWidth="480" MaxHeight="400" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="100"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding gehalt}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="100"></TextBlock>
                <ToggleSwitch></ToggleSwitch>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

Comment: Windows 10 Universal Apps are not WPF, so you shouldn't use that tag for your question. Re-tagged accordingly

Comment: @MatthiasHerrmann Have you been by chance at the Herderschule in Kassel?;)

Comment: No i will study at Universität regensburg @FlorianGl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a ListView with a [GridView](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-with-gridview/). In each `GridViewColumn`, there is a property called `Header`.

EDIT:
You could use a [`ListView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview.aspx#properties). Apparently there is a `ListView.Header` property in W10 apps. Have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.header.aspx). Something like the following could work:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.Header>
        <StackPanel>
              <TextBlock Text="Name"/>
              <TextBlock Text="Money earned"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ListView.Header>
</ListView>
```

Comment: ColumnHeader isnt supported in Windows 10 universal :(

Comment: What does the control template do?

Comment: What about the DataGrid? Is it supported?

Comment: Its not supported either, is there no way to set a header in the listbox, adding manually an item doesnt work either i guess because im using databinding

Comment: @MatthiasHerrmann Ok, sry I thought W10 Apps are just the same as a WPF application. Have a look at my edit.

Comment: Control templates let you redefine the controls visual structure. But im sure W10 apps support a headered `ListBox` so you dont have to do this by yourself.

Answer (score 3):

First of all,ListBox doesn't support Header

I'm not sure if i understand your question correctly, but If you mean you wanna have something like Table (have a header and data in it) I suggest you to use some useful classes like **[MyToolkit](https://github.com/MyToolkit/MyToolkit)** ([DataGrid](https://github.com/MyToolkit/MyToolkit/wiki/DataGrid))

[Helpful question in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228119/create-a-table-datagrid-in-windows-8-metro-apps-c-xaml)